# Логгирование оперативной памяти

Tags: windows-10, логирование, ram

Есть ли в Windows логи, в которых указан объем озу в разные периоды времени? с каким количеством озу загружалась система, или с каким она устанавливалась? Важно отследить пропажу ОЗУ(физичекую)

Comment: Физическая пропажа ОЗУ? Как это возможно? У Гоголя черт луну с неба украл, а как украсть ОЗУ на работающей машине это даже черт не знает. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отследить использование озу нужно кликнуть на "Пуск" правой кнопкой и выбрать "Выполнить", дальше введите perfmon и нажмите Enter. Вы получите доступ ко всем мониторам системы. Дальше вы должны выбрать пункт "Группы сборщиков данных":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше выбираете тут особые и нажимаете "Создать новую группу", вот такое окошко у вас появится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же вы можете создать професиональный отчет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираете какие данные вам нужно получать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше вы добавляете тот вид логов который вам нужен и в итоге можете получить что-то типа такого графика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первоисточником есть [эта](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2009/11/03/how-to-use-perfmon-in-windows-7/) статья. Удачи :)

Comment: Это включит отслеживание ресурса с этого момента. А ОПу, как я понимаю, нужны данные из прошлого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не очень уверен если честно что система хранит такие данные, разве что в каких-то журналах